# Laravel 419 error occurs for a post - form submission even with the csrf_token

Tags: php, laravel, post, csrf-token

I have included  `csrf_field()` like below

```
<form action="/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{csrf_field()}}
// input fields
</form>
```

But i get 419 error for this.
I tried clearing the cache also. But no luck.
Only way i could fix this is to include this path to the `app/http/middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`
I want to know why this happens and how do I fix this without adding path to that file?

Comment: Do you tried with '@csrf'? Laravel transforms it to an input hidden.